# Please help finishing the calculation to find the Entropy of Pareto distribution.

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

Let $X$ follow Pareto distribution with parameters $\alpha, a, h$. That is, $X\sim Pa(\alpha,a,h)$, where $\alpha>0$ is the shape parameter, $-\infty < a < \infty$ is the location parameter, and $h>0$ is the scale parameter.

Then the pdf of $X$ is $p(x) = \left(\alpha\cdot h^{\alpha}\right)/(x-a)^{\alpha+1}$; $x\geq a+h$.

Entropy, $H(X) = -\int_{a + h}^{\infty}p(x)\log p(x)\,dx$

$$H(X) = -\int_{a + h}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha h^{\alpha}}{(x-a)^{\alpha+1}}  \log\left(\frac{\alpha h^{\alpha}}{(x-a)^{\alpha+1}} \right)\,dx$$

$$= -\int_{a +h}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha h^{\alpha}}{(x-a)^{\alpha+1}} \left[\log(\alpha h^{\alpha}) -(\alpha+1)\log(x-a) \right]\,dx$$

$$= -\alpha h^{\alpha}\int_{a + h}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-a)^{\alpha+1}} \left[\log(\alpha) + \alpha \log(h) -(\alpha+1) \log(x-a) \right]\,dx$$

$$= -\alpha h^{\alpha}\int_{a + h}^{\infty} \frac{ \log(\alpha) + \alpha \log(h)}{(x-a)^{\alpha+1}}  dx + \alpha h^{\alpha}\int_{a + h}^{\infty} \frac{(\alpha+1) \log(x-a)}{(x-a)^{\alpha+1}}dx$$

$$= -\alpha h^{\alpha}(\log(\alpha) + \alpha \log(h))\int_{a + h}^{\infty} \frac{ 1}{(x-a)^{\alpha+1}}  dx +  \alpha h^{\alpha}(\alpha+1)\int_{a + h}^{\infty} \frac{ \log(x-a)}{(x-a)^{\alpha+1}}dx $$

Then how can I end up with the result

$$H(X) = -(1+2\alpha)\log(h) – \log(\alpha) + 1 + (1/\alpha)$$

Comment: Do you know about [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: sorry. i am a beginner. i require time to learn LaTex

Comment: don't worry about it - we all had learn how to use it at some point!

Comment: @jkn Thank you for your inspiration.

Comment: I tried to format the question, please check that the edit is what you intended

Comment: @Sathl & jkn Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the following (which can be computed using [standard integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals), [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) and [this limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254420/prove-that-the-limit-displaystyle-lim-x-to-infty-dfrac-logxx-0))

$$\int^\infty_{a+h}\frac{1}{(x-a)^{\alpha+1}}dx=\left.-\frac{1}{\alpha(x-a)^\alpha}\right|^\infty_{a+h}=\frac{1}{\alpha h^\alpha},$$

$$\int^\infty_{a+h}\frac{\log(x-a)}{(x-a)^{\alpha+1}}dx=\left.-\frac{\alpha\log(x-a)+1}{\alpha^2(x-a)^\alpha}\right|^\infty_{a+h}=\frac{\alpha\log(h)+1}{\alpha^2h^\alpha},$$

I get that $H(x)=-\log(\alpha)+\log(h)+1+\frac{1}{\alpha}$ which seems to match up with the entropy listed on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) - are you sure that the end result you list above is correct? I could have mucked a minus sign somewhere - but I can't seem to find it.