# $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+\frac3x+\frac5{x^2})^x$ without L'Hospital

Tags: limits

This is what I get for not

$$L = \lim _{x\to0} \left(1+\dfrac3x+\dfrac5{x^2}\right)^x$$
$$\ln(L) = \lim _{x\to 0}  \left(x \ln \left( 1+\frac3x+\dfrac5{x^2} \right)\right)$$

I don't know how to prove the $\ln(1+3/x+5/x^2)$ though

Comment: Take a look here to write in LATEX.http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Can you find the limit of $(x^2+3x+5)^x$?

Comment: @Did the limit that you mention is = 5^0 = 1 right?

Comment: Right, and then the limit of $x^x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}x\ln(x^2+3x+5)-2\lim_{x\to0}x\ln x=-2\lim_{x\to0}x\ln x$$

Put $y=\frac1x$ and use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254420/prove-that-the-limit-displaystyle-lim-x-to-infty-dfrac-logxx-0)

Comment: I get $x=-2\lim_{x\to\infinity}\frac{ln 1/x}{x} = -2(-1)\lim_{x\to\infinity}\frac{lnx}{x} right?$

Comment: @IndyZa, $$\ln \left(\frac1x\right)=\ln(x^{-1})=-\ln x$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\frac{\ln y}{\sqrt{y}} \to 0, \quad y \to +\infty.$$